# Angular 1.5 return html result in the function by using another component

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, components

Example I have 1 component call 'people' at html like this and its works

```
<html>
    <people data="$ctrl.data" isAlive="$ctrl.status"></people>
</html>
```

But if i want to call people component in another component how ?

I try this solution but it is not working

```
import templateUrl from './main.html';

export const mainComponent = {
    bindings: {},
    templateUrl,
    controller: class MainComponent {
        constructor() {
            'ngInject';
        }

        $onInit() {
            this.data = { name : test }
            this.status = 'ALIVE'
            this.people = `<people data="${this.data}" 
                           isAlive="${this.status}">
                           </people>`
            console.log(this.people) //this should return a html template with 
                                     //  complete data
        }


    }
};
```

Please advise

Comment: In your example you use `templateUrl ` = `'./main.html'`. Where do you want to put `this.people`?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to generate people component template in your controller ? You can just add the component itself in your secondary's component template.

E.g.

angular.module('app',[])

```
.component('people', {
    template:'<div style="color:green;">We are people</div>'
})

.component('alien',{
    template:`<div style="color:red">We are alien but we have people</div>
                    <people></people>`
})
```

**Update**

You can just pass data to your component right after you get it from your external lib.

```
.component('people', {
  template: '<div style="color:green;">We are people, who got some {{$ctrl.data}}</div>',
  bindings: {
    data: '<'
  }
})


.component('alien', {
      template: `<div style="color:red">We are alien but we have people</div>
                        <people data="$ctrl.data.async"></people>`,
      controller: function($timeout) {

        $ctrl = this;

        $ctrl.data = {
          async: null
        }

        function getAsyncData() {
          $timeout(() => {
            $ctrl.data.async = "Fooooo"
          }, 1000);
        };

        getAsyncData();
      }
    })
```

Here's a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npohkLxj/1/)

Comment: Because I using external lib and its function need to create the template and then send to the element of page